# Openpyxl adjust image between two cells

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to adjust image between two cells using openpyxl. My problem is that

```
worksheet.add_image(image, position)
```

method only accepts top-left position of image.

Is there any way how to scale my image between two (top-left, bottom-right) cells?

I tried to compute dimensions using

```
height = sum([worksheet.row_dimensions[start_row+i].height for i in range(img_cols)])
```

and then setting it as

```
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image
Image(image_filename, size=[width,height])
```

but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able to do this in openpyxl 2.5 but will have create and manage your own anchor.