# More precise image placement possible with openpyxl? (Pixel coordinates instead of cell coordinates?)

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm attempting to replicate and automate a well used practice in work: I'm trying to place multiple images and text within a cell in openpyxl, however I can only anchor images to the top left of a cell, and have not found a way to position any more accurately than that. So they end up overlapping with eachother and the text.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
img = Image('image.png')
ws.add_image(img, 'B2') # img.anchor is now 'B2'
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

In the above case 'B2'. I haven't found any way yet to have it take (or convert from) pixel coordinates. But if I could do that then I think I could then format images and text within cells to a legible/acceptable (if not pretty) level.

[image: Mock example of eventual desired output]

Neither **openpyxl.drawing.image** nor **openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet** have an absolute anchor method that I can see. **[openpyxl.drawing.spreadsheet_drawing](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.drawing.spreadsheet_drawing.html)** does but I'm not sure if or how to use it.

Is there a way to do this? Or is there another way I'm overlooking to achieve this goal?

Comment: Relevant [adjust-image-between-two-cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43063292/openpyxl-adjust-image-between-two-cells)

Comment: You can create your own anchorse: OneCell, TwoCell and Absolute, though I think Absolute anchors are only used in ChartSheets.

Comment: @stovfl this post touches on image size and dimensions, which works well (img.height = blah), but still the position placement of the image is only precise to one-cell.

Comment: @CharlieClark would have any info how to make your own anchors? This is where I'm really struglling.

Comment: You're best looking at the OOXML specification, openpyxl will allow you to pass an anchor in with an image.

Comment: Thanks @CharlieClark for the guidance, I ended up digging deeper into the openpyxl library along the lines of your suggestion and found a solution that suits me. I'll answer my own question for future visitors.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

(Edit: This was with Python 3.7 and openpyxl 2.6.1)

So I opened renamed my output excel file to a zip file and found "drawing1.xml" there I could see it was using OneCellAnchor. So following Charlie's suggestion I dug deeper into the openpyxl code and found there was an AbsoluteAnchor class I could use. To set the positions I needed to import XDR coordinates, and then from utils.units some conversion functions from pixel/cm to EMU (excel measurement units?). Then I just set the image anchor to absolute and gave the position and "ext" (dimensions).

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image
from openpyxl.drawing.spreadsheet_drawing import AbsoluteAnchor
from openpyxl.drawing.xdr import XDRPoint2D, XDRPositiveSize2D
from openpyxl.utils.units import pixels_to_EMU, cm_to_EMU

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
img = Image('image.png')

p2e = pixels_to_EMU

h, w = img.height, img.width

position = XDRPoint2D(p2e(500), p2e(500))
size = XDRPositiveSize2D(p2e(w), p2e(h))

img.anchor = AbsoluteAnchor(pos=position, ext=size)
ws.add_image(img) 
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

But this would still be troublesome, as I'd need to know the absolute coordinates for EVERY image I want to place... ideally I still want it anchored to a cell, but then be able to more finely move it within a cell. That's when I noticed that OneCellAnchor has an offset argument. This was perfect, then I made lambda functions with the measured centimetre height and width of default excel cells.

```
from openpyxl.drawing.spreadsheet_drawing import OneCellAnchor, AnchorMarker

c2e = cm_to_EMU

# Calculated number of cells width or height from cm into EMUs
cellh = lambda x: c2e((x * 49.77)/99)
cellw = lambda x: c2e((x * (18.65-1.71))/10)

# Want to place image in row 5 (6 in excel), column 2 (C in excel)
# Also offset by half a column.
column = 2
coloffset = cellw(0.5)
row = 5
rowoffset = cellh(0.5)

marker = AnchorMarker(col=column, colOff=coloffset, row=row, rowOff=rowoffset)
img.anchor = OneCellAnchor(_from=marker, ext=size)
ws.add_image(img) 
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

Which produces:

[image]

Perfect! Exactly the precision I was looking for :)

Comment: Glad you were able to work it out. NB. units are always OS specific so what works on one system might not work on another. And, also, `ws.add_image(img, anchor)` is how I'd do it. Please consider submitting an improvement to the openpyxl documentation.

Comment: @Declan : I cannot thank you enough. For those just wanting to align an image at the top-right of the sheet :  [link](https://gist.github.com/clementlefevre/030ccbd8a936c812a9d510134cf6c6bf)

Comment: This has to be an epitome of bad design. Why do they hide all those features from the users? Why don't they encapsulate this into something useful? Why it seems **they exactly did this earlier and then axed?** (look [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.1/usage.html#inserting-an-image)). Why do even bother with `openpyxl`, then, if this basic feature is present in `xlsxwriter`?

Comment: @z33k because xlswriter can't edit existing Excel files.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore as of Feb 2024

Answer (score 1):

**Here I have added a image in the center of the particular cell (openpyxl==3.0.9)**

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image
from openpyxl.drawing.spreadsheet_drawing import AnchorMarker, TwoCellAnchor
import os

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
row = 1
default_row_height = 75
column_width_for_image = 20

ws.column_dimensions['C'].width = column_width_for_image
ws.row_dimensions[row].height = default_row_height

if os.path.exists('image.jpg'):
    img = Image('image.jpg')

    # Use TwoCellAnchor with offsets for precise positioning and sizing (do some experiment)
    offset_x = offset_y = 30000  # Example offset values for positioning
    _from = AnchorMarker(col=2, row=row - 1, colOff=offset_x, rowOff=offset_y)
    to = AnchorMarker(col=3, row=row, colOff=-offset_x, rowOff=-offset_y)
    img.anchor = TwoCellAnchor(editAs="twoCell", _from=_from, to=to)

    ws.add_image(img)
else:
    ws.cell(row=row, column=3).value = "Image not found"

wb.save("output.xlsx")
```

[image]

Comment: what are the chances you answer this on the day I need it? Worked perfectly, thanks

Comment: what a beautiful coincidence ;)