# how to align image with specific positon and size in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have generated an excel with openpyxl package. In that one column contain an multiple link for attachments and that attachment can be anything like document or image. each cell in the column contains more than one url.
I have parse the url for image and already generated the image for each url. 
My problem is, the images are overlapping. I want to fix thier position in cell.
I don't know how to do that. I also try to align but no use.

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', aa[j])
image_file = io.BytesIO(r.data)
img = Image(image_file)
img.height=100
img.width =100[enter link description here][1]
ws.add_image(img,'G'+str(new_row))
```

above is my code to add image to excel. aa[j] are the image url.

Comment: Try this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78081736/13913019

Answer (score 0):

In an Excel workbook images are laid out on a canvas that sits on top of a worksheet. You can position objects in the canvas using anchors that position them: either from the top-left of the worksheet; from the left-cell; or between two cells. However, this approach is not really suited for layouting and the results will vary between computers viewing the workbook. Nevertheless, if you want to do this you can pass in an `Anchor` object instead of a coordinate as the second parameter of the the `add_image()` method. You will need to look at both openpyxl source code and the OOXML specification to do this properly.

Comment: I have tried this. but not working. can you please tell me how to do it @CharlieClark
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55309671/more-precise-image-placement-possible-with-openpyxl-pixel-coordinates-instead